# Stripe elements createToken with muliple elements

Tags: angular, stripe-payments

I am trying to build stripe into my angular application. The default `this.elments.create('card')` works fine when calling `await this.stripe.createToken(this.card)` but I want to style my inputs separately, so I have done this:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.stripeService
    .setPublishableKey('pk_test_2syov9fTMRwOxYG97AAXbOgt008X6NL46o')
    .then((stripe) => {
      this.stripe = stripe;
      this.elements = stripe.elements();

      this.cardNumberElement = this.createElement('cardNumber');
      this.cardExpiryElement = this.createElement('cardExpiry');
      this.cardCvcElement = this.createElement('cardCvc');
    });
}

onChange({ error }) {
  if (error) {
    this.error = error.message;
  } else {
    this.error = null;
  }
  this.cd.detectChanges();
}

async onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
  const { token, error } = await this.stripe.createToken(
    this.cardNumberElement
  );
  if (error) {
    console.log('Something is wrong:', error);
  } else {
    console.log('Success!', token);
  }
}

private createElement(elementName: string): any {
  const control = this.elements.create(elementName);
  control.mount(this[elementName].nativeElement);
  control.addEventListener('change', this.cardHandler);
  return control;
}
```

As you can see, I am only passing the `this.cardNumberElement` to `await this.stripe.createToken` and that does comeback with a success, but I am not passing the cvc or expiry elements.
How can I pass all elements to the create token method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to pass in the other elements:

> **stripe.createToken** - If applicable, the Element pulls data from other elements you’ve created on the same instance of Elements to tokenize—you only need to supply one Element as the parameter.
>   https://stripe.com/docs/js/tokens_sources/create_token?type=cardElement#stripe_create_token-tokenType

As long as the expiry and cvc elements are mounted and initialized using the same elements instance, their data will be included when creating the token. If you save the token to a Customer, and view the customer's cards in the dashboard you should see the expiry and cvc come through:

[image]

The same is true for validation. If you leave out the expiry date for example, you should notice that even though you're only providing the `cardNumberElement`, Stripe.js will still through an error stating that "Your card's expiration date is incomplete."

Lastly, I should mention that the Tokens API is being phased out in favor of the new PaymentMethods API, which you can use to save card details much in the same way: https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_methods/create_payment_method. Like with Tokens, the PaymentMethods API behaves similarly when separating elements. You only need to provide a cardNumber element, and as long as you mount and initialize the cardCvc and cardExpiry elements using the same elements instances, their values will get pulled in automatically.